# Error: Images Array loop from another images folder in REACT

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to make shopping app in react but i did wrong thing where i dont know.What is the error? 
I want to import images and looping them according to "sku number" but i just fetch header of images. I can't see images, i can't fetch them.

```
<img src="../src/images/{{$product.sku}}.jpg" alt={product.title} />
```

This is the fetch code . I have tried and i'm trying different codes for fetching but it doesn't work. 
Products.js :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import a from "./a.json";
import "./styles.css";

class Products extends Component {
  state = {
    products: a.products
  };

  render() {
    const productItems = this.state.products.map(product => (
      <div className="col-md-4">
        <div
          className="thumbnail text-center"
          style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}
        >
          <a href={product.id} onClick={this.props.handleAddToCart}>
            <img src="../src/images/{{$product.sku}}.jpg" alt={product.title} />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
    return <div className="row">{productItems}</div>;
  }
}
export default Products;
```

And the sight of folders:
[image]

And the sku numbers for matching with photo's names.
[image]

The sight of page
[image]

Comment: What `src` value is being returned on the DOM? It could be a clue

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

`<img src="../src/images/{{$product.sku}}.jpg" alt={product.title} />`

for:

`` <img src={`../src/images/${product.sku}.jpg`} alt={product.title} /> ``

In order for you to embed Javascript into any React component, remember to always enclose your code block in {brackets}. Since backticks belong to Javascript syntax, the enclosing brackets must be added.

Comment: You can just copy it? Or search for it as backtick @TugbaOzkan